# Setting default encoding Openerp/Python

Tags: python, encoding, odoo

Do you guys know how to change the default encoding of an openerp file?

I've tried adding `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` but it doesn't work (is there a setup that ignore this command? just a wild guess). When I try to execute `sys.getdefaultencoding()` still its in ASCII.

Regards

Comment: _Python users who are new to Unicode sometimes are attracted by default encoding returned by sys.getdefaultencoding(). The first thing you should know about default encoding is that you don't need to care about it. Its value should be 'ascii' and it is used when converting byte strings StrIsNotAString to unicode strings._ [DefaultEncoding](http://wiki.python.org/moin/DefaultEncoding)

Answer (score 4):

The comment `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` tells the python parser the encoding of the source file. It affects how the bytecode compiler converts unicode literals in the source code. It has no effect on the runtime environment.

You should explicitly define the encoding when converting strings to unicode. If you are getting `UnicodeDecodeError`, post your problem scenario and I'll try to help.

Comment: I was having `UnicodeEncodeError` but was able to fix it using this `target_item.encode('ascii','ignore')` is there any bad implication when using this?

thanks for the help though

Comment: Using the 'ignore' handler removes the offending characters. That means any character not in the ascii range will disappear in the result string; `u'Crédit'.encode('ascii', 'ignore')` -> `'Crdit'`

Comment: is there any other command/syntax that would just ignore those character and not remove them?

Comment: This is not possible. Unicode characters are 16bit words (or 32bit, depends on python build). It has to be converted to 8bit character. You can use utf-8 instead of ascii. utf-8 will convert any unicode character to a multibyte sequence.